# elasticsearch aggs groupby field and orderby score

Tags: java, elasticsearch

currently I implemented it from postman but I can't implement it from JAVA code. Below is the post json body.
I only want to have the full-text search for Innovation. And groupby email and orderby score. But seems the sum of the score still didn't work. Who can help me out? It worked now.

```
{
"from": 0,  
  "size": 10,
  "query": {  
    "bool": {  
      "must": [  
        {  
          "query_string": {  
            "query": "Innovation"
          }  
        }  
      ]  
    }  
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match": false,
    "pre_tags" : [ "<b>" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "</b>" ],
    "order" : "score",
    "highlight_filter" : false,
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
   "group_by_emails": {
     "terms": { "field": "email" }
   }
 }
  }





SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
searchSourceBuilder.from(0); 
searchSourceBuilder.size(10); 
searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));


QueryStringQueryBuilder queryString = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(keyword);
searchSourceBuilder.query(queryString);

Script script = new Script("_score;");
AggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
        .terms("agg")
        .field("email")
        .order(BucketOrder.aggregation("sum_score", false))
        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_score").script(script))
;

searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregation);

System.out.println(searchSourceBuilder.toString());
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Comment: The Sum of the score still didn't work. Who can help me？

Comment: Thanks anyway. It worked now.